# Connect to private/dovecot-lmtp No such file or directory for postmulti Postfix

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have a second instance of Postfix and problem with connecting to to dovecot-lmtp socket.
In the primary postfix instance everything is OK but for secondary one I have this information in logs:

connect to [MYHOSTNAME].mail.ubuntu.loc[private/dovecot-lmtp]: No such fire or directory

Of course I can add to /etc/hosts IP for [MYHOSTNAME].mail.ubuntu.loc and should works but why in the second instance of postfix [MYHOSTNAME] is added to mail.ubuntu.loc ?

main.cf:[second instance of postfix]

```
compatibility_level = 2
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix-www
mydomain = mail.ubuntu.loc
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = localhost, 192.168.1.19
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
append_dot_mydomain = yes 
biff = no
relayhost = 
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
readme_directory = no
inet_protocols = ipv4
master_service_disable = 
authorized_submit_users = 
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-www
multi_instance_name = postfix-www
multi_instance_enable = yes
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix-www/virtual_mailbox_maps
virtual_mailbox_domains = ubuntu.loc
```

Although I added "mydomain = mail.ubuntu.loc" when I am checking configuration by:

```
$ postconf -c /etc/postfix-www/ | grep mydomain
```

I see: mydomain = [MYHOSTNAME].mail.ubuntu.loc

OK ... my mistake shoud be myhostname = mail.ubuntu.loc instead of "mydomain" option.
But there is still problem with that problem:

```
connect to mail.ubuntu.loc[private/dovecot-lmtp]: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think that I solved the problem.
Secondary instance cant connect to lmtp socket because primary Postfix use it ... I think so
That is why I set inet connection for secondary Postfix instance like that:

dovecot.conf:

```
service lmtp {
    unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
        user = postfix
        group = postfix
        mode = 0660
    }

    inet_listener lmtp {
        address = 127.0.0.1 ::1
        port = 24
    }
}
```

main.cf:

```
virtual_transport = lmtp:127.0.0.1:24
```